# How can I send the current request parameters with a different form submit? Using Laravel and Blade

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-blade, query-string

I have a few forms and several urls with parameters, so my url can look something like:

> myexample.com/users
>
> myexample.com/users?age=10
>
> myexample.com/users?age=10&city=london&hobbies=fishing&eyes=blue&pets=true

I added a search name form so I get

> myexample.com/users?name=john

How can I append the rest of the parameters to the request I just made? Without using sessions.

I tried with hidden inputs in the form but as the rest of the parameters aren't always the same I don't think I can do that without writing a really long list of hidden inputs.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

The request object has a query property which is pointing to the query string handler.

so I imagine your url is something like this

`myexample.com/users?name=john`

```php
$request->query->add(['surname' => 'doe']);

dd($request->query());
```

the output should be

```
array:2 [▼
  "name" => "john"
  "surname" => "doe"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

At your controller just add `$users->appends($request->all());`

Example:

```
public function showUser($request)
    {
        $users = User::whereIn('role', ['Super', 'Admin'])->orderBy('id', 'DESC');

        if (!empty($request->qu)) {
            $users = $users->where('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->qu . '%');
        }

        $users = $users->paginate(5, ['*'], 'users');
        $users->appends($request->all()); //This is what ur looking for :)

        return $users;
    }
```